# Logstash 5.0 Ruby Filter Can't Update Hash in Array

Tags: ruby, filter, logstash

I'm a newbie to both Logstash and Ruby, and I meet a subtle problem today.

My input JSON like the following:

```
{
  "1": "1",
  "2": "2",
  "market": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "m1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "m2"
    }
  ]
}
```

My filter is like the following code, and I want to set event["1"] to m1, event["2"] to m2, event["market"][0]["id"] to m1, event["market"][1]["id"] to m2:

```
filter {
    ......
    ruby {
        code => "
        markets = event.get('market')
        markets.each_index do |index| 
            event.set(markets[index]['id'], markets[index]['name']) 
            markets[index]['id'] = markets[index]['name']
        end
    "
    }
    ......
}
```

And the output is following:

```
{
  "1": "m1",
  "2": "m2",
  "market": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "m1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "m2"
    }
  ]
}
```

The event["1"] and event["2"] get the expected values, but the event["market"][0]["id"] and event["market"][1]["id"] do not, and I want to know why? The desired output should be:

```
{
  "1": "m1",
  "2": "m2",
  "market": [
    {
      "id": "m1",
      "name": "m1"
    },
    {
      "id": "m2",
      "name": "m2"
    }
  ]
}
```

PS: The logstash I'm using is version 5.0.

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: I want a output like:{
  "1": "m1",
  "2": "m2",
  "market": [
    {
      "id": "m1",
      "name": "m1"
    },
    {
      "id": "m2",
      "name": "m2"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of the new [Event API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.x/event-api.html) introduced in the Logstash 5.0. After changing my filter to the following, I get the desired output:

```
filter {
    ......
    ruby {
        code => "
        markets = event.get('market')
        markets.each_index do |index| 
           event.set(markets[index]['id'], markets[index]['name']) 
           markets[index]['id'] = markets[index]['name']
        end
        event.set('market', markets) // comment: adding this setter in the filter
    "
    }
    ......
}
```

According to [Logstash Git Issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5141), "Mutating a collections after setting it in the Event has an undefined behaviour".